# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SolrClient' not found - Apache Solr/PHP

Tags: php, laravel, apache, solr, lucene

Steps followed :

- Installed Solr Apach version 8.7.0
- Followed  [the PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.solr.php) steps for installing and configuring the Solr Extension.
- Created a the project folder on htdocs (xamp) with [the example files](https://www.php.net/manual/en/solr.examples.php) specified in the documentation.
- The code outputs this error : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SolrClient' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\SolrTest\index.php:16 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SolrTest\index.php on line 16
  -this is the line in question:

> $query = new SolrQuery('*:*');

Any suggestions on how to solve this ? I am running this on windows with php 7.

Comment: Does `phpinfo()` show the solr extension installed? Most people use the Solarium PHP library instead of the pecl module these days.

Comment: @MatsLindh I did try phpinfo() and was searching why the extension was not showing up. I guess I messed up somewhere in the installation process right. Also thanks for the info I had no idea solarium was the standard.